# Как создать элемент товара JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx

мне нужно сделать что-то типа элемента товара, что-то типа элементов в интернет магазинах, каждый товар будет иметь фотографию, описание и кнопку "Купить". Более того,нужно сделать, что-бы элементы сами групировались при изменении размеров окна и была возможность добавить такие элементы. Как это лучше всего реализовать?

Comment: Создаете `.fxml` файл вашего товара. Верстаете его. Потом там где нужно его вставить считываете `fxml` лоадером и добавляете куда Вам нужно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделайте макет `.fxml` карточки товара и контроллер к ней с дополнительными полями. Искать по словоформе `javafx custom control`. Потом в программе список этих объектов, создавая их обычным конструктором, помещаете, например, в `flow pane` (это решит вопрос с группировкой), который уже по необходимости помещаете в `scroll pane` (если области экрана меньше, чем товаров). А вот с динамическим изменение `scroll pane` и его содержимого `flow pane` уже есть разные вариации.

Comment: Спасибо, дополню, что для того что бы FlowPane "подгонялся" под размеры ScrollPane достаточно использовать:   scrollPane.setFitToWidth(true);
                                               scrollPane.setFitToHeight(true);